# How to transform several JSON objects using json-c?

Tags: c, json, json-c

I wish to use the **json-c** library to transform all my objects contained in my .json document:

```
{
    "name": "mathieu",
    "password": "def118e47a2f36b73805b01a5fa3f73b506b98166a929802338db6868e28d942",
    "salt": "nXvtCQEqx8l1uNheIJLoO8VI7049vgIS",
    "email": "mathieu@mail.com"
}
{
    "name": "cesar",
    "password": "487b36f3e5a3a74ec3bf2bf48cbc49cde249b08977d22394122c9d512d0e94b4",
    "salt": "Q3QnWFZnLXg8217V1uLaBka6R3CZvCfl",
    "email": "cesar@mail.com"
}
```

In order to transform them (for the moment I just want to display) I use the following code (I followed the instructions from this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQyXuFWylm4&t=0s) ) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <json-c/json.h>

//#include "../../include/personnes.h"

//int parseMyJsonPersonne(){
int main(){
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    char buffer[1024];

    struct json_object *parsed_json;
    struct json_object *name;
    struct json_object *password;
    struct json_object *salt;
    struct json_object *email;

    fichier = fopen("../../data/Personne.json", "r");
    if (fichier != NULL) {
        fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fichier);
    }
    else {
        printf("Une ERREUR est survenue lors du chargement des différents comptes\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fichier);

    printf("buffer : %s\n", buffer);

    parsed_json = json_tokener_parse(buffer);

    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "name", &name);
    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "password", &password);
    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "salt", &salt);
    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "email", &email);

    printf("name : %s\n", json_object_get_string(name));
    printf("password : %s\n", json_object_get_string(password));
    printf("salt : %s\n", json_object_get_string(salt));
    printf("email : %s\n", json_object_get_string(email));

    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "name", &name);
    printf("name 2 : %s\n", json_object_get_string(name));

    free(name);
    free(password);
    free(salt);
    free(email);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is what the terminal shows me after compilation and execution :

```
buffer : {
    "name": "mathieu",
    "password": "def118e47a2f36b73805b01a5fa3f73b506b98166a929802338db6868e28d942",
    "salt": "nXvtCQEqx8l1uNheIJLoO8VI7049vgIS",
    "email": "mathieu@mail.com"
}
{
    "name": "cesar",
    "password": "487b36f3e5a3a74ec3bf2bf48cbc49cde249b08977d22394122c9d512d0e94b4",
    "salt": "Q3QnWFZnLXg8217V1uLaBka6R3CZvCfl",
    "email": "cesar@mail.com"
}

name : mathieu
password : def118e47a2f36b73805b01a5fa3f73b506b98166a929802338db6868e28d942
salt : nXvtCQEqx8l1uNheIJLoO8VI7049vgIS
email : mathieu@mail.com
name 2 : mathieu
```

So here are my various **problems** :

1. How can I go to the next object and know the number of objects in my .json?
2. I think initializing *buffer* to 1024 will cause problems if the number of objects is too large, so is there a way to make buffer take the objects one by one?
3. I have a feeling that the deallocation of memory is not right, did I forget some *free* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_tokener_parse()` returns the first JSON object it finds in the provided buffer. When you call it you place it in a variable called `parsed_json`.

Since the second time you try to get the name you keep passing `parsed_json`,

```
json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "name", &name);
printf("name 2 : %s\n", json_object_get_string(name));
```

the same name is retrieved.

---

What you need to do is continue parsing by calling `json_tokener_parse_ex`. According to [documentation](http://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.13.1/doc/html/json__tokener_8h.html#a6a1583ddd434e13515d6232de813462e), its interface is

```
JSON_EXPORT struct json_object* json_tokener_parse_ex( 
    struct json_tokener *   tok,
    const char *    str,
    int     len 
)
```

where

> **Parameters**
>
> **tok**    a json_tokener previously allocated with `json_tokener_new()`
>
> **str**    a string with any valid JSON expression, or portion of. This does not need to be null terminated.
>
> **len**    the length of str

It basically will parse the input buffer like `json_tokener_parse()`, but using internally the *token* will be able to alert you when something more has to be parsered. This is done by returning **`json_tokener_continue`**.

Please refer to documentation in order to get more info. I just quote here the example shown at the documentation link provided above:

```
json_object *jobj = NULL;
const char *mystring = NULL;
int stringlen = 0;
enum json_tokener_error jerr;

do
{
    mystring = ...  // get JSON string, e.g. read from file, etc...
    stringlen = strlen(mystring);
    jobj = json_tokener_parse_ex(tok, mystring, stringlen);
} while ((jerr = json_tokener_get_error(tok)) == json_tokener_continue);

if (jerr != json_tokener_success)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", json_tokener_error_desc(jerr));

    // Handle errors, as appropriate for your application.
}

if (tok->char_offset < stringlen) // XXX shouldn't access internal fields
{
    // Handle extra characters after parsed object as desired.
    // e.g. issue an error, parse another object from that point, etc...
}
// Success, use jobj here.
```

---

### An alternative solution

As for the other questions, I confirm that first or later you will have problems with your buffer if the number of JSON objects keeps increasing. Dealing with this issue leads to an alternative solution.

**Of course** you can read them one by one, but you will have to perform some parsering yourself while reading from file. But if you are sure that the file structure will **always** be the one you posted in your question you are lucky: what you can do is

1. `fopen()` the file, like now
2. Read from file line by line using `fgets()` instead of `fread()`. Put data in `buffer`
3. Check if the last line contains closing curly bracket `}`. If yes, go on
4. Now `buffer` contains exactly one object. Call `json_tokener_parse()` like you did before, and print the data parsered with `json_object_object_get_ex()`
5. Repeat to point **(2)** until the end of file is reached
6. `fclose()` the file

Comment: Can you pls help me with this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890286/modifying-c-json-string